# Using text as an image is it a right approach?

Tags: css, html

Is it a right approach to use an image with all the information you want (logo, titles, subtext etc), instead of having all the theses elementes in `HTML` tags
 like ,  etc?

Comment: Purse html/css elements might not get you the exact results that you desire, but they are better when it comes to performance.
Images are heavier and requires a request to the server in order for them to load.

Comment: No it is not. Logo can be a image but title and subtext should be **text** within the appropriate tags. Title should go in **Heading Tag** [ `<h1>`/`<h2>`/`<h3>`/`<h4>`/`<h5>`/`<h6>` ] and subtext should go in **paragraph tag**[`<p>`]

Comment: Its depends on you where you use it. too much images in your website make it heavier to load and if you make a responsive website then you want to make images also responsive for each pixels text descriptions are generally make our self responsive and images obviously shows an Abnormal behavior when they display on website.

Comment: This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Comment: At least when it comes to SEO you should have the text in HTML and in Heading Tags. Otherwise the crawler will not be able to analyze your website.